# AVRISP mkII. No comunication betwen programmer and device, after programing fuses

Tags: avr

When I program my Atmega816au, I lose communication with the microcontroller after I program the fuses.

I can write and read the Flash memory with no problems, but only before I program the fuses.

When I program the fuses, the microcontroller becomes "useless" and I don't have access to it anymore.

Comment: If I get Spanish correctly (and I'm not 100% sure that I do), OP loses communication with the ATmega 816au after setting the fuse bits. Flash programming seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Manuel ¿Nos puede decir que los valores que está utilizando para los fusibles de cristal y que estés usando? (Lo siento por Google Translate)

Comment: Thanks AndrejaKo,  your translation it is Ok. Crystal is 3,6864MHz. Fuses: WTDOM, SPIEN, CKOPT, BODEN  are "activated", BODLEVEL = VCC=4V, SUT_CKSEL Ext Cristal/Resonatorhight frecuency start up time 16CK+64mSg

Comment: Can we please stick to English? This site will become a terrible mess if everybody starts using a local language!

Comment: steven, I agree with the main thrust of the argument, but dismissively calling Spanish a "local language" is ridiculous. It is spoken by over 400 million people and is an official language of 20 countries.

Comment: sorry stevenvh,

Comment: @Ranieri - I didn't call Spanish a local language. But it starts with Spanish, and the next day you get questions in Mandarin, Hindi, Arabic and French (to name a few other world languages), and why would it stop there? Why wouldn't I post in Dutch? That's where the local languages come in.

Comment: hello all,  the problem was with the external oscillator. in these conditions it is possible to program the flash but fuses need the external oscillator is well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you program the fuse correctly? An AVRISP mkII uses the SPI serial programming protocol, which can be disabled by fuses. Make sure SPIEN is programmed (0).
Also, you need to select a valid clock to use the SPI serial programming protocol.
Use http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/ to calculate your fuses.

Comment: Thanks, SPIEN is programmed and clock selected in AVRISP mkII programmer is 125 Khz.